# Not able to upload image using Amazon S3 SDK in Android application. 400 error

Tags: java, android, image, amazon-s3

I am trying to implement Amazon S3 SDK to upload image from Android application but always getting this 400 error, malformed xml bad request. I've taken source code from this reference [link](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-simpl3r)

I've correct `access_key`, `secret_key` and `bucket_key`. There is no error related to this.

If anybody have a working sample in order to access this S3 API, please share. I am not able to find SDK error and stuck with the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you to upload image

```
String EXPIRY_DATE = "Mon, Jan 1 2030 11:11:11 GMT";
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCreds);

ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
override.setContentType("image/jpeg");
override.setExpires(EXPIRY_DATE);

File imageFile = new File(path);
PutObjectRequest pros = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET_NAME, BUCKET_PATH, imageFile);
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.addUserMetadata("expires", EXPIRY_DATE);
meta.setHeader("expires", EXPIRY_DATE);
pros.setMetadata(meta);
s3Client.putObject(pros);
```

**EDIT**

Use this for generating URL

```
  String generatedURL=null;
    try {
        String key = BUCKET_PATH + ImageName;
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest urlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, key);
        Date date1 = new Date(EXPIRY_DATE);
        urlRequest.setExpiration(date1);
        urlRequest.setResponseHeaders(override);
        URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(urlRequest);
        generatedURL = url.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error at ", e);
    }
```

Comment: What about the TripsCpnstants and How to get return server url to view the image. Please help

Comment: Edited have you got it, its just the expiry date of your image

Comment: No i didn't get any edits. What if i dont want any expiry date....is it mendatory?

Comment: If you dont set the expiry date it will affect you when you reads the image. Better to set expiry date but not mandatory.

Comment: Ok fine. I will set it but can you please tell me how to receive server path where image is uploaded by this code.

Comment: you mean the entire url?

Comment: Those are my part of code i thought you can able to learn from samples. you are asking the exact ones